# How to hanlde OnClick of map markers when using OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier?

Tags: angularjs, leaflet, overlappingmarkerspiderfier

I just discovers [OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier](https://github.com/jawj/OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier-Leaflet) ***for Leaflet***, and think it could be extremely useful (please note that the Leaflet version offers fewer options than the Google maps version, but I am restricted to Leaflet).

It was the work of only a few minutes to add it an existing project, but I have one tiny problem :-(

When I click any marker from these

[image]

I see the markers briefly expand (spiderify), but then the `OnClick()` of the marker fires (moving me to a new state, showing a new page, without the map).

I guess that I could alter my code to not add an `OnClick()` handler of the marker, until it expands, then add it, so that only clicking an expanded (spiderified) marker will take the action that is currently taken when clicking on a marker.

My question is whether this is the approach that is generally taken. How do ***you*** do it?

Here's my AngularJs code that adds a marker to the map, in case it helps.

```
    // +=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=
    /** Given some data about a single conpany, add an appropriate marrker (and tooltip) to the map */
    Self.AddCompanyMarkerToMap = function (companyData) 
    {
        const companyName = companyData.company_name;
        const latitude    = companyData.latitude;
        const longitude   = companyData.longitude;
        let   iconImage   = 'marker-icon-blue.png';

        if (companyData['currentWorkers'] > 0)
            iconImage = 'marker-icon-green.png';

        //console.log('Add marker to map for company : ' + companyName);

        Self.companyMarkers[companyName] = { lat: latitude, lng: longitude, message: companyName }

        const markerLatLng = L.latLng(latitude, longitude);
        const title = GetCompanyMapMarkerTitle(companyData);

        // see https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.4.0.html#popup
        ////marker.bindPopup("<b>Popup for</b><br>" + companyName);   // replaced by OnClick()

        //console.log('Marker added to map for "' + companyName + '"');

        // see https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.4.0.html#marker
        const marker = L.marker(markerLatLng,
            {
                draggable: false,

                // this is the tooltip hover stuff
                title: title,

                companyId: companyData['company_id'],

                // see https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.4.0.html#icon
                // this is a permanent label.
                icon: new L.DivIcon({
                    ////     className: cssClassname,
                    html: '<img class="my-div-image" src="../common/js/third_party/leaflet/images/' + iconImage + '" />'
                        + '<span style="color:darkblue">' + companyName + '</span>',
                    className: 'dummy',      // hide the square box See https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/291901/leaflet-divicon-how-to-hide-the-default-square-shadow
                    iconSize: [41, 51],      // size of the icon
                    iconAnchor: [20, 51],    // point of the icon which will correspond to marker's location
                    popupAnchor: [0, -51]    // point from which the popup should open relative to the iconAnchor
                })
            }).addTo(Self.map).on('click', Self.CompanyMarkerClicked);

        Self.companyMarkers.push(marker);
        Self.overlappingMarkerSpiderfier.addMarker(marker);

        Self.UpdateMapBoundariesIfRequired(latitude, longitude);
    };      // AddMarkerToMap()
```

Comment: https://github.com/jawj/OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier/blob/1f18a3e994f2d21636d9bd3f6e49cb4d3554a46e/README.textile readme is saying something about spider_click instead of click. check if out it might help.

Comment: Thanks a 1,000,000 (and upvote). I had thought that you had the answer there. But, unfortunately, that is only available in the Google Maps version, and I am restricted to Leaflet, with the Leaflet version not being as feature rich :-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add to the OMS Layer a click event:

```
oms.addListener('click', function(marker) {
  console.log(marker)
  marker.setIcon(greenIcon)
});
```

This is a little confusing but the `click` event is only called when the markers spiderfied and you click on a certain marker or it is a marker which is not in a spider "group"

In [How to use](https://github.com/jawj/OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier-Leaflet#how-to-use)

> Instead of adding click listeners to your markers directly via marker.addEventListener or marker.on, add a global listener on the OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier instance instead. The listener will be passed the clicked marker as its first argument.

Here a vanilla js [example](https://jsfiddle.net/falkedesign/9d2vw5ob/)

I think your code should look like:

```
Self.overlappingMarkerSpiderfier.addListener('click', function(marker) {
  console.log(marker)
  Self.CompanyMarkerClicked(marker); // if you pass the marker
});

Self.AddCompanyMarkerToMap = function (companyData) {
    // ...
    const marker = L.marker(markerLatLng, {
        draggable: false,
        // this is the tooltip hover stuff
        title: title,
        companyId: companyData['company_id'],
        icon: new L.DivIcon({
            ////     className: cssClassname,
            html: '<img class="my-div-image" src="../common/js/third_party/leaflet/images/' + iconImage + '" />'
                + '<span style="color:darkblue">' + companyName + '</span>',
            className: 'dummy',      // hide the square box See https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/291901/leaflet-divicon-how-to-hide-the-default-square-shadow
            iconSize: [41, 51],      // size of the icon
            iconAnchor: [20, 51],    // point of the icon which will correspond to marker's location
            popupAnchor: [0, -51]    // point from which the popup should open relative to the iconAnchor
        })
    }).addTo(Self.map); // <----------- remove the click event

    Self.companyMarkers.push(marker);
    Self.overlappingMarkerSpiderfier.addMarker(marker);
};
```

I saw that you commented

> // see https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.4.0.html#popup

This is the doc of the Leaflet version 1.4.0 the current version is 1.7.1 be careful that you using the correct one ;)

And probably you saw already the Library [Leaflet.markercluster](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster) but maybe it has a few more features that you can need

Comment: Great answer, thanks :-)   I also discovered `osm.addListener('spiderfy', function(markers)` and `addListener('usspiderfy', function(markers)`, although I don't currently need them for my purposes.